# Concrete block VS Red brick for Kitchen extension

Tags: civil-engineering, building-design

Is the wall composition/layers the same if I were to choose either Concrete block or Red brick?

Which has a higher strength?

Which is generally more preferred for extensions?

Note please, this is for a build in the UK. I’m just trying to weigh out my options as builders keep telling me conflicting information

If I’m using the wrong stack exchange, can someone send my question over please?

Comment: Which other stacks do you consider relevant?

Comment: The conflicting info is all true but in different circumstances.  What members are you using to bear tension? (Rebar?) Is your structure trying to avoid loads in tension somehow? (Dome? Limited height?) Strength is one thing, strength per weight is another. Design is nuanced and the best way to choose your material (when they have similarities like this) is to detail two specific designs and compare the results.

Comment: I don’t know Mike- It’s my first time here and I just looked quickly into the stack exchanges around and may have missed one.

Comment: Abel, you’re too technical. I’m just trying to find out which one of the builders is telling the truth- I thought someone could give me a general answers to all of those for a home kitchen extension

Comment: @Jamie you asked at a technical site ... better fit is https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions ... you can delete this post and ask there, if you like